# Assembler listing file missing

Tags: assembly, intel, 8051

I have written a program in assembly for `intel 8051 microcontroller`. I need the `assembler listing file .lst` but I am unable to find it in the directory the program is assembled. The option for assembler listing file .lst is also checked but I am unable to find it in the whole computer. I think assembler is not generating it.

I am using `Keil uVision 4`

How can I generate a .lst file?

Regards

Comment: Are you sure this file isn't deleted at the end by, say, instructions in the makefile or something like that? Also, you should check the path/name as you could be looking for the file in the wrong places.

Comment: I have checked every where. even for the simplest program like for setting and reseting a port for blinking leds, .lst file is not in the directory

Comment: I don't know if this applies: [Linker Code Listing (only for ARM and C51): Generate a code listing file of the complete application (file extension *.COD). For C51 this option is only available when you have enabled Use Extended Linker/Locater (LX51) instead of BL51 and Linker Code Packing (max. AJMP / ACALL).](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_dg_listing.htm).

Comment: this doesn't cover the issue of missing assembler listing file

Comment: If you want to be geeky, try using some of the `windows/system internals` utilities to log the file activity of the toolchain to see if it ever creates this file and where. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the option for the project. To do this:

1. Click on the Project Menu
2. Click on Options for Target
3. Listings tab
4. Then check the Listings you want to output.
5. Select folder for the files to be output.

[image: Listings Tab]